# Is it possible to open terminal from run box and use ' -- ' to run a command to pen a file in some other directory?

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, gnome-terminal

What i want to do is to start a terminal session with the python command line interpreter and and further run a python file using the interpreter the python file could located anywhere.

What i mean to say is I have a python file `demo.py` in `/home/one/two/`

```
#demo.py
a=10
print("something")
```

so that when terminal opens i see the message `something` followed by the console prompt.

```
 something 
 >>>
```

**My approach:**

```
gnome-terminal --python -i ~/home/one/two/demo.py
```

this gives me following result

```
python: can't open file '~/Desktop/pydemo/demo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However when i run the same command from terminal window(not opened in the same directory as the `demo.py` file ) it works properly.

Can someone please explain what is happening here and if possible  suggest a way t0 achieve whatever i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say HOW you start that command. If run from command line,
`gnome-terminal -- python -i ~/demo.py` will work, because the shell will change ~ into your home before the arguments are passed to gnome-terminal. But here in your case, the error message states `~/... : not found` : There was no shell to interpret the ~, so it was left as is, and effectively, there is no directory whose name is the sole character ~ in the directory the command happent to be started in.

Either explicitely use a shell to interpret the ~ :

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'exec python -i ~/demo.py'
```

or do it yourself and proivde the full path name :

```
gnome-terminal -- python -i /home/me/demo.py
```